# Javascript catch method causing error in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse)

Tags: javascript, spring, jhipster

Does anyone know why the Javascript .catch method is causing a syntax error using Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse)? This code is part of a scaffolding application called JHipster. The error is more than likely some Javascript version or configuration problem. New Javascript (EC..something) spec maybe?

Example:

```
angular.module('blackholeApp')
 .controller('ActivationController', function ($scope, $stateParams, Auth) {
        Auth.activateAccount({key: $stateParams.key}).then(function () {
            $scope.error = null;
            $scope.success = 'OK';
        }).catch(function () {
        $scope.success = null;
        $scope.error = 'ERROR';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated to JHipster 3.5.1 and the problem with Javascript went away.